# Print using C++ variadic template

Tags: c++, loops, printf, variadic-templates

I made the task where I have to make print in C# style


```
tprintf("{} world{} {} {} {}\n","Hello",'!',123," Je", "end");
```

And the code is below

```
void tprintf(const char* format) // base function
{
    std::cout << format;
}

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
void tprintf(const char* format, T value, Targs... Fargs)
{
    for ( ; *format != '\0'; format++ ) {
           if(*format == '{'){
                if(format[1] == '}'){
           std::cout << value;
           tprintf(format+2, Fargs...); // recursive call
           return;
           }
        }
        std::cout << *format;
    }
}
```

Now I have to make something little different:

```
tprintf("{1} {3} + {2} = {4} {1}.", "11", 7.5 , 4, 11.5);
```

output:

```
11 4 + 7.5 = 11.5 11.
```

So I think here simple recursion iteration over args doesn't work. I have to know all args which are come to function. I think I should do is at beginning get all args to array and then input them in correct place in pattern string. But how?

I made this

```
template<typename... Args> inline string pass(Args&&...) {return "End";}

template<typename T>
string some_function(T a){
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << a;
    //cout<<ostr.str();
    return ostr.str();
}

  template<typename... Args> inline void expand(Args&&... args) {
    string a="";
        
    a.append(pass( some_function(args)... ))<<endl;

    cout<<" result "<<a<<endl;
  }

struct pass {
    template<typename ...T> pass(T...) {}
  };
```

But this only return "End". I realize cause of this behavior is connected which template behavior and recursion. The last think which is invoke in recursion is
template<typename... Args> inline string pass(Args&&...) {return "End";} so I expand function I get only End string not a string including all args parsed to strings.

So my question is how make this function work fine

```
tprintf("{1} {3} + {2} = {4} {1}.", "", 7.5 , 4, 11.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You end up get something similar to:

`a.append(pass("7.5"), pass("4"), pass("11.5"))`

which appends an "End" to a.

First of all, obviously, cout won't accept your "array" here, even you actually give it an array. And you need output the parameters one by one. So you have to extract every single one by recursion.

Comment: But what I do when I have more parameters or less?

Answer (score 0):

You might use lambda functions.

```
template< typename ... args >
void tprintf( char const * fmt, args const & ... a ) {
    std::array< std::function< void() >, sizeof ... (a) > fmt_fun
        = { [&a]{ std::cout << a; } ... };

    for ( ; * fmt; ++ fmt ) {
        ...
        std::size_t fmt_n = * fmt - '0';
        fmt_fun[ fmt_n ](); // print nth argument
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that there is no need for metaprogramming-style recursive pack iteration.

Hmm, this [code works in Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=891712dd78d744db84279da5b9bd9ea9-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336) but in GCC runs afoul of a [longstanding bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933).

Comment: But I get some errors : parameter packs not expanded with '...':| in this line "= { [&a]{ std::cout << a; } ... }; " and some errors connected to fmt_fun first said error: 'fmt_n' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: @Aku Are you using GCC? Also, the lines which just say `...` are pseudocode. You should replace that with your `{x}` parsing. I tested it using Clang, with the only change being to remove the `...` lines, and it converted `tprintf( "021", "Hel", "rld!\n", "lo, wo" );` to `Hello, world!`.

Comment: Shouldn't `sizeof...(a)` be `sizeof(args)`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Both `a` and `args` are parameter packs, so `sizeof ... (args)` would also work. But I'm interested in the length of the pack which is `sizeof ...`, not the number of bytes in the type which is  plain `sizeof`.